# Cannot read property 'style' of null in three places at once

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

When I run my code it give me this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at onlyShowInput1H (/:673:42) at showInputH (/:995:9) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (/:85:117

In more detail here is what code does:

user inputs 1-10 tasks in the 1st div user inputs 1-10 tasks in the 2nd div (stored in localStorage)
user inputs 1-10 tasks in the 3nd div(stored in localStorage)
A do list is displayed with all the inputs the user inputed(stored in localStorage)
This error is being displayed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined at /script.js:66:5 TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at onlyShowInput1H (/ITHB.js:457:42) at showInputH (/ITHB.js:779:9) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (/:85:104)

I think the second error is affecting my code, from saving the 21st input because it's not reading it

Here is a link to a plunker of my code: https://plnkr.co/edit/HbT4WKFpqQrW5Ikv?open=lib%2Fscript.js

And here is a code snippet (not of my entire code but the part that isn't working):

```
function showInputH(){
  var numHAI = document.getElementById('numHAI');
   if (numHAI.value == 0){
    alert("If you don't have any, click I don't have any hard assignents");
   }
    else if (numHAI.value == 1){
        onlyShowInput1H();
        showSaveH();
    } else if (numHAI.value == 2){
        onlyShowInput2H();
        showSaveH();
    } else if (numHAI.value == 3){
  } else if (numHAI.value == 4){
        onlyShowInput4H();
        showSaveH();
    }  else if (numHAI.value == 5){
        onlyShowInput5H();
        showSaveH();
    } else if (numHAI.value == 6){
        onlyShowInput6H();
        showSaveH();
    } else if (numHAI.value == 7){
        onlyShowInput7H();
        showSaveH();
    } else if (numHAI.value == 8){
        onlyShowInput8H();
        showSaveH();
} else if (numHAI.value == 9){
        onlyShowInput9H();
        showSaveH();
    } else if (numHAI.value == 10){
        onlyShowInput10H();
        showSaveH();
    } else{
      alert ("Try doing between 1-10 hard assignments OR click I dont have any hard assignments today if you dont have any");
    }
}
```

Comment: No logic in the provided snippet is accessing a style property of any Element.

Comment: Before you continue, take a look at some nice data structures JS offers: [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays) and [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).